# Ubuntu can't progress past boot

Tags: boot

On reboot, GRUB 2.04 starts up,

1st option UBUNTU returns

```
/dev/nvme0n1p3: recovering journal
/dev/nvme0n1p3: clean, 138733/60022784 files, 189923044/240068608 blocks
[      4.545063] cgroup1: Unknown parameter ‘memory_recursiveprot’

[  TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/C950-22C5
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /boot/efi.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Local File Systems.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Clean up any mess left by 0dns-up.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for File System Check on /dev/disk/by-uuid/C950-22C5
[  TIME ] Timed out waiting for device /dev/disk/by-uuid/a7e6035e-774f-4faf-a97e-621fe9b51fa0.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for /dev/disk/by-uuid/a7e6035e-774f-4faf-a97e-621fe9b51fa0.
[DEPEND] Dependency failed for Swaps.
[.    94.799333] proc: Bad value for ‘hidepid’
[FAILED] Failed to start Load Apparmor profiles.
You are in emergency mode. 
After logging in, type "journalctl -xb" to view system logs, 
"systemctl reboot" to reboot, "systemctl default" 
or”exit” to boot into default mode.
Press Enter for maintenance
(Or press Control-D to continue):
```

The journalctl logs are predominately fine, featuring some warnings, and a repeat of the Timed out waiting for device messages on `/dev/disk/by-uuid/C950-22C5` and `/dev/disk/by-uuid/a7e6035e-774f-4faf-a97e-621fe9b51fa0`.

Additionally, there is a red `cgroup2: Unknown parameter 'memory_recursiveprot'` message, and another red `Failed to start AppArmor profiles.`

```
df | grep -v loop
```

returns:

```
Filesystem     1K-blocks      Used Available Use% Mounted on
udev            65758668         0  65758668   0% /dev
tmpfs           13158132       740  13157392   1% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p3 944074904 743369768 152675032  83% /
tmpfs           65790648         0  65790648   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs               5120         0      5120   0% /run/lock
/dev/sdb1       15008576     11856  14996720   1% /usb
```

(the /usb mount is attached manually to get the logs etc out)

> blkid | grep -v loop

returns

```
/dev/nvme0n1p1: UUID="C950-22C5" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="bad697e3-db9c-40e8-9b13-6599f5268208"
/dev/nvme0n1p2: UUID="a7e6035e-774f-4faf-a97e-621fe9b51fa0" TYPE="swap" PARTUUID="cefd1777-5563-44d1-80e2-5ddf0383ad73"
/dev/nvme0n1p3: UUID="55a10f71-7156-47e5-beaf-a3bc6f5437e7" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4" PARTUUID="ae5ea471-1a3d-46fc-99ad-a710074131a8"
/dev/sda: LABEL="Storage" UUID="74811583-21d7-495b-aaeb-eb48a30a4897" BLOCK_SIZE="4096" TYPE="ext4"
/dev/sdb1: UUID="28E8-161B" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="vfat"
```

and /etc/fstab contains:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/nvme0n1p3 during installation
UUID=55a10f71-7156-47e5-beaf-a3bc6f5437e7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/nvme0n1p1 during installation
UUID=C950-22C5  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/nvme0n1p2 during installation
UUID=a7e6035e-774f-4faf-a97e-621fe9b51fa0 none            swap    sw              0       0
```

If I run `mount -a` the `/boot/efi` disk is found and attached, despite timeout-ing at boot time.

I have tried some non-invasive things, like mounting drives, commenting out disks on fstab etc, but so far, anything I've tried continues to result in remaining in emergency mode.

I've tried having grub start in recovery mode, but this fails due to the same errors identified above, leaving me in limbo.

The fact that /boot/efi starts after a `mount -a` confuses me, isn't that what the timeout is complaining about at boot-time? And if I can easily mount that manually from emergency mode, how come it's unavailable when required?

Can anyone help me diagnose the issue, or identify a minimal fix? I'd like to avoid re-installing the OS if at all possible.